# How to stop filtering of custom filters while loading in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have created custom filter called myFilter for date range.

```
app.filter('myFilter',function($filter){
    return function(items, from, to){
        return $filter('filter')(items, 'start_date', function(v){
            var date = new Date(v);
            return date >= moment(from) && date <= moment(to);
        });
        return false;
    };
});
```

Data is not showing until select the date range. I want show all the data while page loading. Here is the filter that i used:

```
<div ng-repeat="project in projects | myFilter: projectfilterstartdate : projectfilterenddate | filter: project_type_filter" >
```

Comment: Probably `projectfilterstartdate` or `projectfilterenddate` or both are null when the controller loads, therefore all of the entries are filtered out. Try to set default values for when the controller first loads.

Comment: If we set default values it will not display all the data right?

Comment: Depends what values you'll give them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Muli Thanks for the info. I defined the values initially like this. It's working.

```
    app.filter('myFilter',function($filter){
        return function(items, from, to){
            var start_date = (from && !isNaN(Date.parse(from))) ? Date.parse(from) : 0;
            var end_date = (to && !isNaN(Date.parse(to))) ? Date.parse(to) : new Date().getTime();
            return $filter('filter')(items, 'start_date', function(v){
                var date = new Date(v);
                return date >= moment(start_date) && date <= moment(end_date);
            });
       };
});
```